# Portfolio immunization in time

Tags: duration

The company will have to pay out an amount of liabilities $13594$ at the moment $t=9$. In $t=0$ they want to cover it with 4-years zero-coupon bonds and yearly perpetual annuity that is due in arrears using immunization strategy (match the duration of portfolio assets with the duration of future liabilities). How much (in %) has to change share of perpetual annuity in portfolio in $t=1$ to keep portfolio immuziation? Interest rate r=8%.

My approach: 
At the momment $t=0$:

$$p_1\underbrace{Duration_{0}(bonds)}_{4}+p_2Duration_{0}(annuity)=\underbrace{Duration_{0}(liabillities)}_{9} $$

At the momment $t=1$:

$$ p_1^{'}\underbrace{Duration_{1}(bonds)}_{3}+p_2^{'}Duration_{1}(annuity)= \underbrace{Duration_{1}(liabillities)}_{8} $$

Where 
$$ p_1=\frac{PV_{0}(bonds)}{PV_{0}(bond)+PV_{0}(annuity)}=\frac{PV_{0}(bonds)}{13594v^9}, \\ p_2=\frac{PV_{0}(annuity)}{PV_{0}(bond)+PV_{0}(annuity)}=\frac{PV_{0}(annuity)}{13594v^9}$$
$$ p_1^{'}=\frac{PV_{1}(bonds)}{PV_{1}(bond)+PV_{1}(annuity)}=\frac{PV_{1}(bonds)}{13594v^8}, \\ p_2^{'}=\frac{PV_{1}(annuity)}{PV_{1}(bond)+PV_{1}(annuity)}=\frac{PV_{1}(annuity)}{13594v^8}$$

For perpetual annuity $Duration_{0}(annuity)=Duration_{1}(annuity)=:D$.
So we have simultaneous equations

$$
(\star) \begin{cases}
4p_1+Dp_2=9 \\
3p_1^{'}+Dp_2^{'}=8 \\ 
p_1+p_2=1 \\
p_1^{'}+p_2^{'}=1
\end{cases}
$$

Thus

$$
\begin{cases}
4\frac{PV_{0}(bonds)}{13594v^9}+D\frac{PV_{0}(annuity)}{13594v^9}=9 \\ 
3\frac{PV_{1}(bonds)}{13594v^8}+D\frac{PV_{1}(annuity)}{13594v^8}=8 \\ 
\frac{PV_{0}(bonds)}{13594v^9}+\frac{PV_{0}(annuity)}{13594v^9}=1 \\
\frac{PV_{1}(bonds)}{13594v^8}+\frac{PV_{1}(annuity)}{13594v^8}=1
\end{cases}
$$

And I cannot solve it and generally don't know if the approche is right. I'd be really appreciate it if somebody could help me out with that exercise.

Edit:

Duration for perpetual annuity is dependent only on interest rate:

$D=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kv^kCF}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} v^kCF}=\frac{Ia{\infty}}{a_{\infty}}=\frac{\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}}{\frac{1}{r}}=1+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1.08}{0.08}=13.5$

If we insert it to $(\star)$, then we get $p_2=\frac{5}{9.5}=0.526, p_2^{'}=\frac{5}{10.5}=0.476 $. So $p_2^{'}-p_2=-0.05$ and the right answer is $-0.0228$.

Maybe somebody detects what is not ok here? In this solution I don't use information that the amount of liabillities is $13594$ so probably there is some other (right) solution.

Comment: I haven't followed your reasoning carefully, but normally I would start precisely from the calculation of the PV *and the Duration* of the liability of 13594 at t=9.